# How to use Vuforia and ARKit in the same scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, arkit

How can I switch between Vuforia and ARKit?
I want to get the position of the marker using Vuforia, and then switch to ARKit and place a 3D object in this position.

What is a better way to switch between them?

Both packages use their own camera prefabs, so should I create 2 different scenes and switch between them, or is there a way to use Vuforia and ARKit in the same scene (maybe disable one and enable another one at the same time)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new Vuforia 7 SDK, I believe you are developing in Unity so enable AR in Unity XR Settings. I'm trying to do something similar. I have both Vuforia and ARKit running the same scene. 
This is what I have done so far:

1. disable ARKit so Vuforia can detect the marker
2. Keep a reference to the augmented object generated by the marker as
3. Disable Vuforia once marker is detected
4. Setup ARKit configurations and run with it (I then called on update the position of the ARKit camera so I can see in my screen as I move it the positions update and that only the ARKit camera is running)

Now I'm at a stage where I use the position of the augmented object created by the marker and simply tell ARKit to display a object as this position but the problem is that it will have a new coordinate system and the position the augmented object first showed up at will mean nothing in ARKit. Best thing to do is find something in the Vuforia scripting to find the Vuforia coordinate system and use that in ARKit somehow